# Strange Jquery issue preventing click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, onclick

I am experiencing a strange issue which seems to be preventing click actions on links.

If you visit: http://goo.gl/7nN8p you will see three horizontal menu items in the enter of the page each of which displays a div within which there are 6 links. The issue I am having here is that none of the three horizontal links or any of the 6 links within the divs can be clicked thus preventing you from visiting the associating links.

Any ideas what might be going on here and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

there's a javascript error on this page.
Look at firebug when you click an item, it fires:

```
$($anchor.attr("href")).offset() is null
 scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
```

Comment: thank you but can you by chance provide any further details in regards to how this might be resolve?

Comment: I should clarify that I resolved the javascript error but the issue still continues with not being able to click on any of those links.

Comment: you probably want to change `var $anchor = $(this);` to `var href = $(this).attr('href')` in `jquery-scroll.js`

Comment: Obviously I am not going to debug your application for you. Hope my tip helped a little bit.

Comment: I actually removed the jquery scroll script completely.